# Why can't 'var' be used in for loop in Go?

Tags: go

I'm new to Go, and there is a question.

As I know, the following two snippets are basically the same.

```golang
i := 0

var i = 0
```

but why can't `var` statement be used in for loop?

```
for var i = 0; i < 10; i++ {
    //do something
}
```

There will be a `syntax error: var declaration not allowed in for initializergo`

Why is it designed this way? Are there any thoughts in it?

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me.

Comment: I guess for simplicity? Why would you ever want to use var in the init statement as you will allways give it an initial value. (And therefore the type can always be implicit.)

Comment: Because the language spec says so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialisation statement in [this form of the `for` clause](https://golang.org/ref/spec#ForClause) can't be any kind of statement but must be a ["simple statement"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#SimpleStmt) (one case of such statements is the ["short variable declaration"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#ShortVarDecl) you saw working).

As for the reason, it's just like many other choices in the Go language: to keep your code readable and looking like the Go code of other developpers: if you could put any kind of statement here, the `for` loop wouldn't always be easily identifiable (and would mix concerns other than loop initialization).

Comment: Close Reason: primarily opinion-based. Your answer is an opinion.